# How to create dynamic form inputs using javascript based on a database array

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, loops

I'm hugely struggling with a javascript form creation loop based on a database. The difficulty lays in the array which is multidimensional.

**The array from the database:**

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [Diplome] => Master 
        [Institut] => IAE 
    ) 
    [1] => Array ( 
        [Diplome] => Licence 
        [Institut] => Université
    )
)
```

**Javascript trial:**

```
<?php $array = "array from db above"; ?>

<script type="text/javascript">

var arr = <?php echo json_encode($tr, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT) ?>;
var length = arr.length;

function createForm(){
    for (i in arr) {
        
        form = document.getElementById("formed");

        var x = arr[i].Diplome;
        var y = arr[i].Institut;

        var input = document.createElement('input');
        input.setAttribute('value', x)

        var input2 = document.createElement('input');
        input2.setAttribute('value', y)

        form.appendChild(input);
        form.appendChild(input2);
    }
}

</script>
```

**Expected result:**

```
<form id="formed">
<div>
<input type="text" name="diploma" placeholder="Diplôme" value="Master">
<input type="text" name="institut" placeholder="Institut" value="IAE">
</div>
<div>
<input type="text" name="diploma" placeholder="Diplôme" value="Master">
<input type="text" name="institut" placeholder="Institut" value="IAE">
</div>
</form>
```

Any idea ? Thanks a lot from France !

Comment: What is the issue you are facing?

Comment: does the form exist before trying to call this function? The expected result does not follow the code you have

Comment: whats `$tr`? you only making two `<input value=""/>` you need add alot more to achieve your expected result.. whats the question?

Answer (score -1):

```
var arr = <?php echo json_encode($tr, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT) ?>;
```

is returning a `string`. So you need to  `JSON.parse(arr)` to iterate over it using your `createForm` function.

```js
// This is what the return value of json_encode in PHP will look like
var arr  = `[ 
    { "Diplome": "Master", "Institut": "IAE" }, 
    { "Diplome": "Licence", "Institut": "Universit\u00e9" }
]`;

var arr = JSON.parse(arr)
var length = arr.length;


function createForm(){
    for (i in arr) {
        
        form = document.getElementById("formed");

        var x = arr[i].Diplome;
        var y = arr[i].Institut;

        var input = document.createElement('input');
        input.setAttribute('value', x)

        var input2 = document.createElement('input');
        input2.setAttribute('value', y)

        form.appendChild(input);
        form.appendChild(input2);
    }
}


createForm()
```

```html
<form id="formed"></form>
```